# Kitchenette vs. kitchen electrical circuits

Tags: kitchens

I am living in a mother-in-law suite in the lower level of a 2003 home.   I just had a 6ft. kitchenette installed.  I will use a small fridge, a toaster oven, and a coffee pot.   The electrician installed one circuit that covers 3 wall plugs, only one of which (on top of counter, not fridge) has test/reset buttons (not sure what those are called).   Is this single circuit installation up to code?  Kitchens require 2 circuits, but what about a small kitchenette?

Comment: A kitchen is defined as: An area with a sink and permanent provisions for food preparation and cooking. if there is a installed oven or cook top this would meet the definition and would require 2 circuits. Many electricians will run a multi wire branch circuit to provide the 2 required circuits. If no permanent fixtures are installed your install could be legal unless local codes require the additional circuit.

Comment: Does the kitchenette have a sink plumbed?

Comment: Also the single GFCI (plug with buttons) may be protecting the other ouletets.  Try this, press the Test button (not reset just yet tho, only test)... No plug something into each of the three outlets.  My prediction is they will all be off.  Now press Reset and they will all be back on again.

Answer (score -2):

It called a Gfi outlet as long as the gfi is in the first outlet in the line from breaker it will trip before it gets to breaker box even if the last outlet shorts out our gets wet that is code in most states you are good and safe with that type of install

Comment: GFIs don't generally trip on a short circuit, at least that's not their purpose. In fact it should not trip if the short is line to neutral. You may want to read up on how GFIs work. Also, try writing in sentences, your stuff is hard to read. Also, as stated above, kitchens require two circuits, which is what the OP is asking about.